# Regexp for an array with 2 elements

Tags: ruby, regex, rspec

I don't know if exist a regexp in ruby to say that you are expecting an array with 2 integers inside and that each number cannot be upper than 10 or lower than 0. And that the add of both numbers cannot be upper than 10. I've been looking for in internet but I haven't found anything usefull. I hope you can help me. Thanks¡¡

My attempt has been something like

```
expect(game.player.shoot).to eq([\d[0-10],\d[0-10]])
```

But I know is not working at all...

Comment: Can you give an example (input plus expected output)? It's not clear how the array is represented in the string to which the regex is applied.  Note that requiring two integers to be non-negative and sum to at most 10 implies that each integer is not more than 10.

Comment: Downvote is mine, for posting a vague question and not responding to requests for clarification (mine and @floum's). I will retract the downvote if you clarify with an edit.

Comment: I was trying to test that a method player.shot returns me an array with two integers, and each of them are equal or higher than 0 and equal or minor than 10. I'm doing the Kata Bowling. But anyway I've been trying another better ways. I'm sorry for the late answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather not use a regex to check for values in an array.
Are your values strings? If so, should not they really be strings or parsed earlier?

If they are already integers, this should do the trick :

```
expect(game.player.shoot.all? {|s| (0..10).include?(s) }).to be_true
```

To check that their sum is not greater than 10 :

```
expect(game.player.shoot.reduce(:+)).to be <= 10
```

Comment: Yes. They are integers. I've used your first solution and is been usefull to me. I've used for testing that a method returns an array with integers from 0 to 10. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go in the regexp way, I would suggest you to use something like the following.

It is done in two steps on purpose because you are testing two different things and to keep assertions isolated.

```
expect( game.player.shoot.count ).to eq(2)
expect( game.player.shoot ).to all( match(/[0-9]|10/) )
```

That, as said before in other answers would only work if game.player.shoot is an array of **Strings**, otherwise the last line should more like

```
expect( game.player.shoot ).to all( (be >= 0).and(be <= 10) )
```

or

```
expect( game.player.shoot ).to all( satisfy{ |shoot| (0..10).include? shoot } )
```